# Force ListViewItem to occupy all ListView width

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, width

I have a `ListView` and I want to add some children. I want that these ListViewItems (for example `Border` instances) have a Height of 25, and a Width equal to that of the ListView, even when I resize the ListView.

I try the following code to add 10 elements:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    ListPsw.Items.Add(new Border 
    { 
        BorderThickness = new Thickness(2), 
        BorderBrush = Brushes.Black, 
        Margin = new Thickness(5),
        Height = 25
    });
}
```

and this is the result:

[image]

But I want something like this:

[image]

How can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set `HorizontalContentAlignment` property to `Stretch`.

```
<ListView Name="ListPsw" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" />
```